# Override файлов Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть файл

```
/bitrix/modules/main/include/urlrewrite.php
```

Нужно внести в него правки.

Перенес его в папку

```
/local/bitrix/modules/main/include/urlrewrite.php
```

, внес изменения, но они не применились.

Далее решил привязаться к событию в init.php, однако, не нашел в документации события, которое происходит в момент перехода в карточку товара магазина (нужно отследить наличие, и если 0, то выполнить некоторые действия).

Подскажите, как правильно сделать override нужного файла в Битрикс, во избежание правок ядра?

Comment: Данный файл относится к ядру битрикса и его не получится изменить. Перенос в локал ничего не даст

Comment: urlrewrite для редактирования обычно лежит в корне сайта.

Comment: коллеги правильно говорят: файл не модифицируется, переопределить его нельзя, такой функционал система не предлагает, т.к. считается что в нем нет необходимости. Могли бы вы описать что именно вас там не устраивает и зачем вы хотите его изменить? Быть может тогда мы сможем дать вам совет как сделать это корректно

Comment: Нужно редиректить пользователя на родительскую категорию в случае, когда товар, на страницу которого он (юзер) переходит, неактивен. Я думаю, в этом файле можно было бы разместить соответствующий метод.

Comment: поскольку он отвечает за 404- й редирект